# Revenge serial-downvoter with a few downvotes per time

Tags: support, reputation, voting, downvotes, serial-voting

I don't know why, but today someone that I don't know who, voted both of them in a few seconds. I'm sure this is serial downvoting, because these two questions have nothing to do with each other and both were voted up enough times and never voted down.

I know that the system automatically reverses serial vote down, but I'm afraid that system don't care about two vote downs, so didn't consider this as serial vote down and don't fix my reputations.

What should I do about that?

Also I have absolutely no idea who did that.

Comment: The question linked to doesn't address people trying to circumvent the anti-serial-downvoting mechanism.

Answer (score -42):

The prime reason this kind of things happens is because SO allows anybody to downvote without providing   any rationale as to why they are downvoting a questions. This actually encourages irresponsible downvoting.